# how to implement a list of paragraph word lengths using a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've never used stackoverflow before, I usually stay over at the math and physics sections.  I'm a reactor physicist, not a programmer, and this is literally the first week I've been toying with Python 2, so please don't chastise me.

I'm supposed to make a list "wordLenLi" that contains the lengths of the words from a small paragraph using a for loop.  The short paragraph is in the batch file

This is what I've tried.  I've also tried messing around with the append() method.  This little dinky book doesn't do much justice.

```
st = '''April is the crueles month, breeding
Lilacs out of the dead land, mixing
Memory and desire, stirring
Dull roots with spring rain.'''

x = st.upper()

wordLi = x.split(' ')

for n in wordLi:    
    z = len(n)
    WordLenli = z.split()
    print wordLenLi
```

Comment: well, that didn't work

Comment: hang on, I'll yonder around till I figure out how to post my code

Comment: Check [the help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), it explains markdown formatting. Essentially, for code, just indent it by four spaces. (or for inline code, surround in backticks - `\``)

Comment: And why did I get flagged down?

Comment: Is making the text upper-case needed for your answer?

Comment: Ah, so that's how the formatting works.

Comment: Yes!  I monkeyed with that for about two hours.  Never would have thought to put the for loop in the variable.

Comment: @Greg It's called a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw), and is a specific feature, rather than 'putting it in the variable'. Once you understand how they work, they are really useful.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  Much like how a volt is sometimes called a "Jiggawatt"... Oh how the many times I've heard it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a list comprehension. List comprehensions are essentially a powerful shorthand for writing for loops. A basic list comprehension takes the form `[expr for variable in iterable]`. It goes over each value in `iterable`, assigns it to `variable` and then stores the result of `expr` in a list. So

```
WordLenLi = [len(word) for word in st.split()]
print(WordLenLi)
```

Produces

```
>>> 
[5, 2, 3, 7, 6, 8, 6, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 3, 7, 8, 4, 5, 4, 6, 5]
```

As a for loop it would look like this

```
WordLenLi = []
for word in st.split(): #for each word in a list of words
    WordLenLi.append(len(word)) #insert the length of the word into WordLenLi
```

Alternativley, as a demonstration:

```
WordLenLi = [(word,len(word)) for word in st.split()]
print(WordLenLi)
>>> 
[('April', 5), ('is', 2), ('the', 3), ('crueles', 7), ('month,', 6), ('breeding', 8), ('Lilacs', 6), ('out', 3), ('of', 2), ('the', 3), ('dead', 4), ('land,', 5), ('mixing', 6), ('Memory', 6), ('and', 3), ('desire,', 7), ('stirring', 8), ('Dull', 4), ('roots', 5), ('with', 4), ('spring', 6), ('rain.', 5)]
```

You could also have it shorter than the first comprehension:

```
WordLenLi = map(len,st.split())
```

**Also**, as per Jon Clement's suggestion, you way want to replace `st.split()` with something like this:

```
re.findall(r'\b[\w\d%s]+\b' % string.punctuation,st)
```

Which would require you to import the *re* and *string* modules via `import re,string`.

Comment: +1, This is the optimal answer, but the question states 'using a for loop', so it might be necessary to expand out the [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) (a link to an explanation of list comprehension, as to newbies they can be daunting) into a loop for the purposes of education.

Comment: Short of using NLTK to parse the paragraph, it might be better to replace `str.split` with either an `re.findall ('\w+', s)` or similar with specific chars, or the inversewith `re.split` - to not count punctuation as word length (eg `month,`)

Comment: @JonClements Good point, I'll update the answer as per your point

Comment: Note that in 3.x, `map()` will produce a generator, not a list (the OP appears to be using 2.x though, so should be fine for them).

Comment: Thanks folks, there's apparently a lot more traffic here than on the physicsSE or mathSE.  Thanks for putting up with me.  Thanks HennyH, now... onto another problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I like HennyH's answer, but just so you don't get the impression that list comprehensions are theo nly possible answer, we also have :

```
for word in paragraph.split() : 
    print(word.len())
```

The problem with original was:

```
z = len(n)
WordLenli = z.split()
```

You were trying to "split" a number as if it was a string.  The general lessons are:

- Reducing the number of moving pieces reduces potential bugs.
- It helps to remember what kind of thing each of the named objects is.

I think those principles work as well in physics as they do in programming, but it is easy to lose sight of them when trouble starts.